# PHP debugging Linux

Tags: php, linux, debugging, logging

Hi I am using Komodo Edit and I want to debug my code, what I am doing so far is seeing the log in /var/logs/apache2/error.log, but I want to see it on the browser itself.
How can automatize this¿? I have tried to add those 2 lines at the start of my php file without success:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Any idea¿? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: That should do it. What exactly do you mean with `without success`, what kind of errors to you expect to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the value of **display_errors** in *php.ini* to **on**, change the value of **error_reporting** to something like *E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE*, save the file and then reset the Apache server you have (or whatever server you have), in order to set those changes in place.